# Rank of a matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be the $n\times n$ matrix whose $i,j$ entry is equal to $i+j$.

I have to find the rank of $A$.
After reducing $A$ to row echelon form when $n=2$ or $n=3$, I have found out that all columns are linearly independent, so intuitively I think that for the general case, the rank must equal $n$. But how can I prove it? 
Any help will be appreciated .

Fix:I made a dumb mistake while reducing my matrix to row echelon form, now I have found that the rank is always 2, am I right?

Comment: Do you mean the *rank* of $A$?

Comment: Are you sure? Can you show us your work for $n=3$?

Comment: yes sorry, I was thinking in my native language, let me fix that

Comment: @user1551 Oh,thanks man, after reducing my 3x3 matrix again I found I had made a mistake and one column was a linear combination of the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The rank is always two. Your matrix is $A=uv^T+vu^T$, where $u=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ and $v=(1,2,\ldots,n)^T$. With this form, one can easily prove that $Ax$ is always a linear combination of $u$ and $v$, and hence the rank of $A$ is *at most* 2. If you can further prove that the image of $A$ indeed contains two linearly independent vectors, you are done.

Comment: Thanks, I should be able to prove it now.